# Are T4A and T4AL the same kind of fuse?

Tags: fuses

A power supply for some equipment I have blew its fuse. The fuse holding is labeled `T4A` `250v`. When I look for replacements online, the fuses I can find all appear to be `T4AL`, not `T4A`. Are these actually the same kind of fuse, and can I use a `T4AL` fuse?

Comment: L might be for long as in slow-blow. So the fuse doesn't trip on startup inrush currents like motors.

Comment: @DKNguyen No it isn't, because the "T" already means slow-blow.

Comment: Straight glass versus sand-filled?

Answer (score 1):

They could be the same type, but it should be verified somehow, as it may be up to manufacturer interpretation.

T4AL means a slow-blow 4A fuse with low interrupt current capability.
T4AH means a slow-blow 4A fuse with high interrupt current capability.

The former should be good for interrupting approximately in the order of 10-100A of short circuit current, while the latter should be good for in the order of 1000A.